# How to factor a delete request between modules in Mongoose/MongoDB (Callback Hell)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, crud

I'm making a CRUD List App using Mongo/Express and having callback trouble!

I have a **routes** file with my HTTP methods and a **services** file that pulls in my mongoose model, `Item`.

Because this is from a class I'm taking I already have a GET and POST that are running correctly, but having a total headache trying to get my DELETE working.

**Routes.js**

```
router.post('/items', function(req, res) {
Item.save(req.body.name, function(item) {
    res.status(201).json(item);
}, function(err) {
    res.status(400).json(err);
});
});

router.delete('/items/:id'), function(req, res) {
var ref = req.params.id;
Item.remove(ref, function(err, item){
  res.json(item);
})
};
```

**Services.js**

```
exports.save = function(name, callback, errback) {
Item.create({ name: name }, function(err, item) {
    if (err) {
        errback(err);
        return;
    }
    callback(item);
});
};

exports.remove = function(id, callback){
Item.findByIdAndRemove(id, callback())
};
```

Obviously my delete/remove is still pretty CRUD.... Included the POST for reference. Help would be amazing as attempts at translating existing examples into my architecture have been total fails!

Answer (score 1):

Your punctual problem is that you execute the callback instead of passing it into the mongoose method in the remove function:

```
exports.remove = function(id, callback){
Item.findByIdAndRemove(id, callback())
};
```

should be, so that mongoose can call it:

```
exports.remove = function(id, callback){
Item.findByIdAndRemove(id, callback)
};
```

I wonder why you feel it necessary to wrap the the mongoose methods findByIdAndRemove, and create with your own and to put them in a service?  The new methods don't seem to add any value.

If you want to do things before or after deleting the model, it would be more idiomatic to trap the mongoose model life-cycle methods using middleware: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html.

Comment: That and if you used the mongoose methods directly, you could take advantage of the promises they return. You're actually losing functionality by wrapping them in your services as-is.